# Possible Unicode Japanese Digits/Decimals?

Tags: unicode, ascii, non-ascii-characters, cjk

I am trying to support/convert Japanese digits/punctuation for currency and so I am considering the following characters.

> ０１２３４５６７８９。．

I am mapping all of the digits to their ASCII counterparts and the last 2 punctuation to an ASCII decimal.

My product does not support commas.

Are these all the possible variations of digits/decimals for Japanese keyboards? I can't find an exhaustive list.

Answer (score 2):

You do not need to list up all possible patterns but ask adequate normalization libraries.

in Python

```
import unicodedata
print(unicodedata.normalize("NFKC", "１２，３４５．６７"))
```

in JavaScript

```
"１２，３４５．６７".normalize('NFKC')
```

in PHP

```
<?php
if (!class_exists('Normalizer')) { exit ('You need to turn on php_intl extension.'); }   
echo Normalizer::normalize('１２，３４５．６７', Normalizer::NFKC);
```

the results

```
12,345.67
```

Just to make sure, Japanese period(。) is not used for decimal point so you should not convert it, as the libraries above do not.

Comment: The problem is that normalization occurs with those libraries where I do not want it to, for example with subscript numbers and fractional numbers, and I am not sure this is the desired behavior in all cases. Also, why would the NFKC library not convert the Japanese period? It seems like it should be converted..

Comment: @AdamThompson Because using the same dot letter for both full-stop and decimal point is only Western writing habit. Japanese period had been there for long as a Japanese full-stop letter (i.e. it was not made from European period letter), it has never been a decimal point letter.

Comment: Those unicode handling libraries are based on [ICU library](http://site.icu-project.org/), where thousands of people around the world has been working for decades. I believe it covers up pretty broad standard cases. You may check their specifications and implementations if you want.

Comment: I looked into it and it looks like it is because normalization is meant for normalization between similar looking characters for the same abstract character within the same script, not for normalization between scripts for intent like I am asking in the OP.